# popup panel that docks to the bottom of the screen

Tags: css, gwt, layout

How do I create a pop panel that docks to the bottom of the screen...

The way that I'm doing this is by setting the styling as such:

bottom: 10px;
position: absolute;

This will always set the panel to 10 px from the bottom of the browser window.

The problem is that gwt (or gwtp for that matter) is insisting on setting the right and the top of the panel and thus overriding my styling. If I use chrome's element explorer and disable the right and top style rules I get the correct behaviour so one way of doing it is somehow disabling gwt setting of the location of the panel on the screen...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you need to increase the precedence of your rules by using `!important` on them to override what GWT is setting on them.

Also, the default values for `top` and `right` would need to be reset to their default, which is `auto`, not `0`.

Try this:

```
.mySelector {
    bottom: 10px !important;
    position: absolute !important; 
    /* You could also try position: fixed !important; here
    if the element should be fixed by screen position
    rather than containing element position */
    right: auto !important;
    top: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks - as it turns out, I'd already tried that but got the syntax for !important wrong. That's exactly what worked.

Comment: the use of !important must be overkill. Surely GWT and GWTP provide a cleaner route to setting an app's styling.

Comment: No there isn't, and I'd appreciate you removing your downvote on a correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
element-selector
{
    bottom: 10px; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Hopefully gwtp won't override.